# What should I take care while migrating AWS from One Region to other ( Singapore to Mumbai )

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

We are about to migrate from AWS Singapore to Mumbai. What all should I be aware of during this region migration  or any other ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Some AWS services are not supported in all regions. For example, Lambda is not available in Mumbai. Make sure all your required services are available in your destination regions.
2. There are many instance types not supported in particular regions. For example, m3 instances are not available in Mumbai. This is because now we should be using m4, but there is nothing like `m4.medium`. m4 class starts with large. So, you have no option but to go to `t2.medium`. Make sure your required instance types are available in your destination region.
3. Some MySQL RDS versions are not available in Mumbai; hence you can't directly migrate them. You will need to first upgrade your RDS to the closest MySQL Version. The best way to migrate RDS is to create a read-replica in the destination region and then promote read-replica to master.
4. In all older regions (eg Singapore), S3 supports both Signature Version 2 & 4 but in newer regions (eg Mumbai) only Signature Version 4 is supported. This was a shock for us when we realized that all our AWS CLI, SDK for Java started failing when buckets migrated to the Mumbai region. The solution is to upgrade your SDKs and then specify the region while making S3 request.

For us, it was a challenge as we had to migrate from AWS Java SDK 1.8 to 1.11.11 and AWS had stopped using many basic classes like JSONObject, JSONArray etc. We were using these classes for JSON manipulations in our application codebase. Hence, lots of code re-write was needed in hurry.

5. S3 buckets which are really huge and constantly getting updated cannot just be migrated to another region. You cannot just delete this bucket and create a new one in destination region (after some time) because sync can take many days.. We might be ok with downtime of some time but not of 1-2 days.

Now two options: First if you can change bucket name; then u can have zero downtime: create new bucketname in destination region and start sync.. Make sure that on origin bucket you have enabled "Cross Region replication" which makes sure to add any NEW item to destination bucket. If this is not enabled; aws sync might never able to catch up.  Once sync is complete; you can change your codebase and deploy. If you are using CDN; don't forget to change origin there also.

If you cannot change bucket name; there will be some downtime ( depending on how big the bucket is). Here repeat procedure in first option; then delete origin bucket --> create another bucket in destination region with same name after some time --> sync two buckets both in same destination region.. this sync would be much faster because it is in same region.

This is not a complete list; just a few pain points that we encountered.

Comment: Great observations!